# SQL Query help needed here

Tags: sql

I have a query with 4 columns like the following

```
(Select PAPROJNUMBER, PACOSTCATID,EMPLOYID, PADT,  PABase_Qty from PTE10001 
where padt between '2017-04-09' and '2017-04-11'
order by PADT)
```

and I get the result like this:

```
PAPROJNUMBER    PACOSTCATID    EMPLOYID        PADT                  PABase_Qty
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001        2017-04-09 00:00:00.000 1.00000
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001        2017-04-09 00:00:00.000 2.00000
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001        2017-04-09 00:00:00.000 2.00000
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001        2017-04-09 00:00:00.000 4.00000
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001        2017-04-09 00:00:00.000 6.00000
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001        2017-04-10 00:00:00.000 3.00000
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001        2017-04-10 00:00:00.000 4.00000
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001        2017-04-10 00:00:00.000 2.00000
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001        2017-04-11 00:00:00.000 0.00000
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001        2017-04-11 00:00:00.000 0.00000
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001        2017-04-11 00:00:00.000 3.00000
```

I am looking for something like this as an output

```
PAPROJNUMBER    PACOSTCATID    EMPLOYID      PABase_Qty 4/9/17 4/10/17  4/11/17 
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001         1.00    1.00    3.00   0.00 
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001         2.00    2.00    4.00   0.00 
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001         2.00    2.00    2.00   3.00 
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001         4.00    4.00    0.00   0.00 
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001         6.00    6.00   0.00    0.00
```

Can you please help with a query like this?

Comment: I made a mistake by typing the column PAbase_qty here in the output. It is not required. Just the date with quantity under it. PAPROJNUMBER PACOSTCATID EMPLOYID 4/9/2017 4/10/2017 4/11/2017
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001         1.00   3.00  0.00 
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001         2.00   4.00  0.00 
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001         2.00   2.00   3.00 
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001         4.00  0.00  0.00 
HOTELEDGER      CONSULTING      ACKE0001         6.00  0.00  0.00

Comment: So the output should be

Comment: In sqlserver try using Pivot. Check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot

Comment: 4 columns? I'm countinng 5: PAPROJNUMBER, PACOSTCATID, EMPLOYID, PADT,  PABase_Qty.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to pivot it out. Add more case statements as necessary:

```
select PAPROJNUMBER, 
    PACOSTCATID, 
    EMPLOYID,
    sum(case when PADT = '2017-04-09' then PABase_Qty else 0 end) as date_4_9_17,
    sum(case when PADT = '2017-04-10' then PABase_Qty else 0 end) as date_4_10_17,
    sum(case when PADT = '2017-04-11' then PABase_Qty else 0 end) as date_4_11_17
from PTE10001
where PADT between '2017-04-09' and '2017-04-11'
group by PAPROJNUMBER, 
    PACOSTCATID, 
    EMPLOYID
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the help. When I am trying to run it, it is giving me an error like "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference". Any idea about it?

Comment: oh you are using sql server, so numbers in group by won't work. just updated it with actual column names

Comment: I am sorry but this is not working. This is not about summing it up as you have highlighted above.